# After unsubscribing topic still getting push notification + Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented topic subscription in firebase when I subscribe to the specific topic I am getting a notification for that topic but when I unsubscribe to that topic then also I am getting a notification for that topic.

Is it take a time to unsubscribe topic?

```
Messaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "topic name")

Messaging.messaging().unsubscribe(fromTopic: "topic name")
```

Answer (score 1):

Unsubscribe can take an entire day to register.

Comment: is there any document which specifies about this?

Comment: I just looked and couldn't find anything, but this is definitely an issue that I am familiar with. From my trials it almost always took a day before it worked. Sorry I can't offer better advice than my word.

Comment: Let me wait till 1 day and check it is working or not.

thanks for ur reply.

Comment: Let me know if it doesn't work; I might be able to find where I implemented it in my code if the issue persists.