# iOS push notification to topic except sender

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification

I'm sending push notification when post is created using firebase to the topic where all devices are registered. This works fine, except the author of the topic obviously receives notification as well (which is not preferred behaviour).

The first approach I took was to unsubscribe the user (author) from the topic before sending the notification and then resubscribe him back. This was working, but only in same cases. I [found out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45205817/after-unsubscribing-topic-still-getting-push-notification-firebase) that unsubscribe can take up to 1 day to take place. And it looks like it is true. After I unsubscribed the user and check the [status](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server), the user was not subscribed to the topic, but he was still receiving topic notification even few minutes later.

So I've decided to take another approach - implement Notification Service Extension, which should have ability to [suspend notification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_usernotifications_filtering). I've added the userId as a notification parameter and I'm comparing this ID with userId that is logged on the device. The comparison is working, however I'm not able to suspend the notification.

Using the method from Apple Documentation to call completion handler with empty object:

```
contentHandler(UNNotificationContent())
```

The notification is displayed anyway. There is a note that:

> To silence a remote notification, you must set the apns-push-type header field to alert when you send the notification to the APNS server. Otherwise, the system always displays the notification banner to the user.

So I have added that to the header. This is how the whole JSON body which I'm sending to Firebase looks like:

```
{
  "to": "/topics/debug",
    "mutable_content" : true,
    "notification": {
        "title": "Title",
        "body": "Notification body",
        "sound": "default",
        "badge": 1,
        "consultant_id": 202513
    },
    "apns":{
      "headers":{
        "apns-push-type": "alert"
      }
    }
}
```

I'm wondering how Facebook, WhatsApp or other similar services works? Because they have this feature implemented somehow. The only other option I'm thinking of is to send notification to individual devices, which looks like overkill to me.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to exclude specific users from receiving push notifications in iOS. You can use a custom key-value pair in the payload, a Notification Service Extension (NSE), or a third-party library.

Custom key-value pair: You can add a custom key-value pair to the notification payload that includes the user ID of the one who posted the data. For example, you could add a key called posterId or userId. When your app receives the notification, you can check this value to see if it matches the current user's ID. If it does, you can choose to ignore the notification.

Notification Service Extension (NSE): An NSE is a piece of code that runs on your device when it receives a push notification. You can use an NSE to modify the notification before it is displayed to the user. For example, you could use an NSE to check the user ID and, if it matches the current user's ID, you could choose to cancel the notification.

Third-party library: There are a number of third-party libraries that can help you send push notifications to iOS devices. Some of these libraries may offer features that allow you to exclude specific users from receiving notifications.

Facebook and WhatsApp: Facebook and WhatsApp likely use a combination of these approaches to send push notifications to their users. For example, they may use a custom key-value pair in the payload to identify the user who posted the data. They may also use an NSE to check the user ID and, if it matches the current user's ID, they may choose to cancel the notification. Finally, they may also use a third-party library to help them send push notifications.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the approach I'm taking to use NSE to filter the notification if userId match, however the problem is that even after telling NSE to filter the notification when the condition is met, the notification is displayed anyway.

Comment: If your Notification Service Extension (NSE) is not properly filtering notifications when the condition is met, ensure that the NSE is correctly set up and linked to your app. Check the implementation of the NSE's code and verify that the `didReceive(_:withContentHandler:)` method is being called. Review the logic within the NSE to ensure that notifications are properly cancelled when the condition is met. Test the app and NSE on a physical iOS device for accurate behavior. Maybe Apple has some limitations for notification service extensions?